Combining Queues with RabbitMQ in ASP.NET Web API
I am developing an application using ASP.NET Web API and Angular with two main functionalities:
File Upload: Users can upload files, and upon successful upload, the server generates URLs for these files. I need to publish these URLs to a RabbitMQ queue.
Template Creation: Users can create templates, which also need to be published to another RabbitMQ queue.
Problem: I want to merge the messages from the two queues (the file URLs and template details) before processing them together. The final goal is to send emails that include the uploaded files as attachments whenever a template is created.
 var factory = new ConnectionFactory
    {
        HostName = _rabbitMqSetting.HostName,
        UserName = _rabbitMqSetting.UserName,
        Password = _rabbitMqSetting.Password
    };
    _connection = factory.CreateConnection();
    _channel = _connection.CreateModel();
}

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    StartConsuming("alertQueue", stoppingToken);
    StartConsuming("anotherQueue", stoppingToken);

    await Task.CompletedTask;
}

private void StartConsuming(string queueName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName, durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);
    consumer.Received += async (model, ea) =>
    {
        var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

        bool processedSuccessfully = false;
        try
        {
            processedSuccessfully = await ProcessMessageAsync(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Exception occurred while processing message from queue {queueName}: {ex}");
        }

        if (processedSuccessfully)
        {
            _channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
        }
        else
        {
            _channel.BasicReject(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, requeue: true);
        }
    };

    _channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName, autoAck: false, consumer: consumer);
}

private async Task<bool> ProcessMessageAsync(string message)
{
    try
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var emailService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IEmailSender>();
            var vsoService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IVsoService>();
            var alertTypeService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IAlertTypeService>();
            var s3Service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IFileService>();

            var alertMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AlertMessage>(message);
            var uploadMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileUploadMessage>(message);

            if (alertMessage != null && uploadMessage != null)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"AlertMessage: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(alertMessage)}");
                _logger.LogInformation($"FileUploadMessage: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(uploadMessage)}");

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("Both AlertMessage and FileUploadMessage must be present in the message.");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (JsonException jsonEx)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"JSON error processing message: {jsonEx.Message}");
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Error processing message: {ex.Message}");
        return false;
    }
}

public override void Dispose()
{
    _channel.Close();
    _connection.Close();
    base.Dispose();
}

}

RabbitMQ, have message grouping is a method that associates related messages with a unique identifier to ensure they are processed in the correct order. This is important because multiple consumers may be working concurrently.

@PowerMouse could you please explain more how can i solve my issue

The question has nothing to do with Spring Framework which is only for Java.

you can dequeue multiple grouped messages. or if you dequeuing from different queues so you can use DB to store separate parts and pieces to combine them together.
